# I am missing [New Folder] Button in Windows 8.1 Save As Dialog

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, save-as

One day my new folder (and organize) button just disappeared from my save as dialog. I use that button all the time so I was surprised to find it missing. To make sure I wasn't crazy I did a quick internet search, and sure enough:

**EDIT: Default explorer:**
[image]

**THIS IS WHAT I HAVE** (Added more pictures from different programs, names are below picture)
[image]
Web Download^^
[image]
Notepad^^
[image]
Powerpoint (2007)^^
[image]
Word (2007)^^

---

**THIS IS WHAT WINDOWS 8 IS SUPPOSE TO HAVE:** (This is random a picture from internet, from google search "windows 8.1 save as")
[image]

This has affected all of my save as dialogs, such as saving a document in word, saving and edited picture, movie, you name it. Can someone PLEASE help, this is driving me insane!!!

Comment: Interesting. It only disappears for me in folders I cannot write to.  But even in those cases, the toolbar still exists, and the Organize button is there.

Comment: I am in the process of doing some research, but I need to know, can you create a new folder on your desktop?

Comment: What program is the first dialog from percisely?  There exists two difference save as dialogs, one which is supported in Windows 7 and above the other for leagacy systems.  Depending on the age of the program its very likely, the lack of the "new folder' is intended due to the Win32 library call the program is making.  *Please provide more specific examples.*  [Related](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/add-create-new-folder-windows-explorer-8-save-as/62718772-1d79-40e3-8166-7b2087f2188d)

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I can still create folders, currenly I am using right click new folder.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll add some more pictures from different programs in post

Comment: @Ramhound I added some more pictures, and all of the programs I put USED to have the New Folder and organize option. I have no idea what it is.

Comment: if you boot into a minimal boot configuration, this means you manually configure your system to only boot what is required for it to actually boot, does this behavior still exhibt itself?

Comment: I cannot do that right now, would this have anything to do with a custom theme? (I am using UXTheme with aeroglass)

Comment: How does a regular Windows Explorer window look for you? Also, yes: Custom themes are most likely the culprit. They aren’t supported, after all.

Comment: @DanielB added screenshot of normal File Explorer. Everything is fine except for save as dialog box.

Comment: Remove your custom theming (and any associated programs), try in Safe Mode, try while logged in as a different user, report back.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ok, I'll get back to you once I can.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yup, It was my custom theme (8plus). I guess I'll have to go without it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of commenters, it was my custom theme. Specifically, 8plus. It was for some reason removing the bar that was containing the buttons, so I removed the theme and the New Folder button was restored.

Comment: It’s most likely a bug in the theme. You should report it to the creators, perhaps they can fix it.

Comment: @DanielB I would love to report the bug but I think the creators have lost interest, so...